# Unable to invoke javascript function from blazor component

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to check if my blazor web assembly app is opened on mobile or not. For that,

I created a wwwroot/script.js file and added code:

```
function isDevice() {
   return /android|webos|iphone|ipad|ipod|blackberry|iemobile|opera mini|mobile/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
}
```

Added reference in index.html

And then in my component:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRunTime
@code {
private string isDevice { get; set; }
private static bool mobile { get; set; }

protected async override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        mobile = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>("isDevice");
        isDevice = mobile ? "Mobile" : "Desktop";
    }
    await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
}
}
```

I'm getting an error on compile time that:

> No overload for method 'InvokeAsync' takes 1 arguments

[image: Please check this image as well.]

After checking the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.jsinterop.jsruntime.invokeasync?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_JSInterop_JSRuntime_InvokeAsync__1_System_String_System_Object___

I changed the code to have second parameter like this:

```
mobile = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>("isDevice", new object[] { });
```

Now the error is:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
> property 'JSRuntime.InvokeAsync(string, object[])'

[image: second error]

Comment: Yeah it takes two arguments... look at docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.jsinterop.jsruntime.invokeasync?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_JSInterop_JSRuntime_InvokeAsync__1_System_String_System_Object___

Comment: try  JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>("isDevice", new []{});

Comment: @Milney I changed it to `JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>("isDevice", new object[] { });` but now the error is:
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>(string, object[])'

Comment: the second paramter is object[]

Comment: You must have removed your @inject IJSRuntime JSRunTime line... You should have got this error even before the change otherwise

Comment: Ah its casing - your inject has JSRunTime while your code has JSRuntime - Notice the lowercase vs capital T for Time/time

Comment: @Milney, thank you for pointing me in this direction. I wasn't missing the line but I had a typo in the name that I was using.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> @inject IJSRuntime JSRunTime

The issue is related to the above line. If using the above injected name (JSRunTime), in the code block, if we hover the JSRunTime, we can see it is an instance of Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime, instead of the injected object.

[image]

To solve this issue, try to change the injected object name, like this:

```
 @inject IJSRuntime JS
```

Then, you could use the injected object as below:

```
        @inject IJSRuntime JS
        <p>
            <button @onclick=ShowConfirm>Confirm popup</button>
        </p>
        <p>
            <button @onclick=ShowPrompt>Prompt popup</button>
        </p>

        @code { 
            private string Result;
            private async Task ShowConfirm()
            {
                bool confirmed = await JS.InvokeAsync<bool>("confirm", "Are you sure?");
                Result = confirmed ? "You clicked OK" : "You clicked Cancel";
                Console.WriteLine(Result);
            }

            private async Task ShowPrompt()
            {
                string name = await JS.InvokeAsync<string>("prompt", "What is your name?");
                Result = "Your name is: " + name;
                Console.WriteLine(Result);
            }

        }
```

The result like this:

[image]

Reference:

[Call JavaScript functions from .NET methods in ASP.NET Core Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Answer (score -2):

**C# Code:**

```cs
[Inject]
IJSRuntime JS { get; set; }

 private async Task Delete()
 {
     if (!await JS.InvokeAsync<bool>("confirm", $"Are you sure you want to delete?"))
     {
         return;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Please elaborate how your code fixes the issue from the question.